# Rebol switch and type?

Tags: rebol

Why do I have to cast typeof to string with switch to make it work ?

This doesn't work:

```
  typeof: type? get 'optional
  switch typeof [
    word! [
      print "word"
    ] 
    string! [
      print "string"
    ]           
  ]
```

This works:

```
  typeof: type? get 'optional
  switch to-string typeof [
    "word" [
      print "word"
    ] 
    "string" [
      print "string"
    ]           
  ]
```

Comment: REBOL is a simple language, but contrary to Carl Sassenrath's assertions, it isn't necessarily an easy language. :) Simple != Easy.

Comment: Then let's say it's an Elegant Language :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
switch type?/word :optional [
    word! [ print "word" ]
    string! [ print "string" ]
]
```

OR

```
switch type? :optional reduce [
    word! [ print "word" ]
    string! [ print "string" ] 
]
```

The reason is that the REBOL doesn't reduce ("evaluate") the cases in the switch statement. Without the `/word` refinement, the `type?` function returns a `datatype!`, but the switch statement tries to match this against a `word!`, and it fails.

I realize this might be confusing, so your best bet is either to convert the type to a string (as you did), or use one of the two idioms I've suggested. I prefer the first one, using `type?/word`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you're a Rebol Guru for sure : I didn't know /word did exist :)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about `/word` either, until a helpful commenter pointed it out to me on my blog. :)